# C# WhenAny Cancel call not working causing thread accumulation

Tags: c#, multithreading, cancellation-token

It's most likely a really stupid mistake but I cannot figure this out and I've spent almost 2 days on this.
I have an app that with a button click launches 5 tasks running in parallel but each with its own delay.  This part works fine.
However, if you click the same button again, it doesn't cancel previously launched tasks and creates another instance.  So basically creates more and more tasks that run in parallel.  I obviously have code trying to cancel tasks if the button is clicked more than once but for some reason it doesn't work.
Could someone point me to my issue?  Or is this code is beyond repair and needs total revamp?  Thank you!
If you execute this WPF app and click on the button, you will see that ping frequency just keeps on increasing.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace TestMultiThreadWithDiffSleeps
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Binding
        private string m_output0;
        public string Output0
        {
            get { return m_output0; }
            set { m_output0 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string m_output1;
        public string Output1
        {
            get { return m_output1; }
            set { m_output1 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string m_output2;
        public string Output2
        {
            get { return m_output2; }
            set { m_output2 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string m_output3;
        public string Output3
        {
            get { return m_output3; }
            set { m_output3 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        private string m_output4;
        public string Output4
        {
            get { return m_output4; }
            set { m_output4 = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

        private static SemaphoreSlim ThreadSemaphore;
        private CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSrc;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            ThreadSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1);
        }

        private async void ButtonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await StartToMonitor();
        }

        private async Task<bool> StartToMonitor()
        {
            M_Stop(); // Stop everything in case this is a restart

            CancellationTokenSrc = new CancellationTokenSource();
            bool taskResult = await M_Start();
            CancellationTokenSrc = null;

            return taskResult;
        }

        public void M_Stop()
        {
            Output0 = string.Empty;
            Output1 = string.Empty;
            Output2 = string.Empty;
            Output3 = string.Empty;
            Output4 = string.Empty;

            if (CancellationTokenSrc != null)
                CancellationTokenSrc.Cancel();
        }

        private async Task<bool> M_Start()
        {
            List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

            // Build task list
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                int iIdx = i; // Need to do this when multi-threading
                int sleepTime = (i + 1) * 1000;

                tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    while (!CancellationTokenSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        if (!Ping(iIdx))
                            return false; // Ping in this example always returns 'true' but you can imagine in real life there'd be 'false' returns that shall cancel all threads

                        await Task.Delay(sleepTime); // Delay for different length of time for each thread
                    }
                    return true;
                }, CancellationTokenSrc.Token));
            }

            Task<bool> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
            bool result = firstFinishedTask.Result;
            CancellationTokenSrc.Cancel(); // Cancel all other threads as soon as one returns

            return result;
        }

        private bool Ping(int index)
        {
            ThreadSemaphore.Wait(); // Not needed for this app...  here only because it's in my other app I'm troubleshooting

            switch (index)
            {
                case 0: Output0 += "*"; break;
                case 1: Output1 += "*"; break;
                case 2: Output2 += "*"; break;
                case 3: Output3 += "*"; break;
                case 4: Output4 += "*"; break;
            }

            ThreadSemaphore.Release();

            return true;
        }
    }
}


<Window x:Class="TestMultiThreadWithDiffSleeps.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Margin="0,30,0,0" Click="ButtonStart_Click"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Output0}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Output1}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Output2}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Output3}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Output4}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues in this code.

The source of the problem you're describing is this:

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (!CancellationTokenSrc.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
```

The tasks always check the token of the current `CancellationTokenSrc`. So unless the cancellation happens in the exact moment between `Task.Delay` calls where the tasks check `IsCancellationRequested`, they'll just see the new, uncancelled CTS you create after a restart.

You should pass the current `CancellationToken` as a method argument or store it in a local variable inside `M_Start`, instead of checking the shared `CancellationTokenSrc` field to avoid this problem.

Slight improvement: `Task.Delay` also has an overload that accepts a `CancellationToken`. It will throw a `TaskCanceledException`.

Additionally, you're updating the `OutputX` properties from parallel threads (`Task.Run`), which then raise the `PropertyChanged` event that's supposed to update the UI. This kind of cross-thread UI interaction isn't safe, you will need to involve the `Dispatcher` to make sure the event is raised on the UI thread.

Lastly, the ownership of `CancellationTokenSrc` is fairly complex and seems ripe for race conditions as multiple concurrent methods use and set it. In case of a restart `M_Start` could easily cause a `NullReferenceException` when it tries to cancel `CancellationTokenSrc` which has already been set to `null` in `StartToMonitor`.

Comment: Thank you for all the tips.  I implemented your recommendations with passing the the token and adding token to `Task.Delay` and now I get an "A task was canceled" exception on `Task<bool> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);` line on the second button click.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make `Task.Delay` cancellable too:

`await Task.Delay(sleepTime);`

Change it to:

`await Task.Delay(sleepTime, CancellationTokenSrc.Token);`